# Using EventSource to flush the PHP output buffer

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to get a PHP script to run "in the background" when a page is visited. This script processes approximately 10,000 database records, so I would like the user to be able to see the progress of the script as it works through them all. I have been looking at [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to do this, but I'm hitting a couple of issues.

Firstly, the code doesn't seem to flush (currently to the console, eventually to the page) until the code has finished running. Ideally it should flush after every record.

Secondly, the event doesn't stop processing when the PHP reaches the end of the script, and it re-runs the code. My console ends up getting filled with the output multiple times.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    // to-do: on click
    var outputEvent = new EventSource("{{ url(['for': 'batch-pull', 'event': eventCode]) }}");

    outputEvent.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    // to-do: disconnect
    // end on click
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
public function batchPullAction($eventCode) {
    $visitorsLink = 'visitors/?limit=1000&event=' . $eventCode;
    $visitors = $this->getVisitors($visitorsLink);

    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream' . "\n\n");

    ob_start();
    $countMe = 0;
    foreach ($visitors as $visitorCode) {
        $countMe++;
        $pull = new Pull($eventCode, $visitorCode);
        try {
            // $log = $pull->process();
            echo "event: message\ndata: " . $visitorCode . ' = OK<br>' . "\n\n";
            sleep(1);
        } catch (N200Exception $e) {
            echo $visitorCode . ' = ' . $e->getCode() . ': ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if ($countMe == 10) {
            break;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    ob_end_clean();
    exit;
}
```

**Output**

```
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "2fwteo2kfazuq = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "0dce1ezp890n4 = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "3js6n4yh94nwq = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "2lnwisow0rduv = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "3f8c0mn2qpi3n = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "2pf4212ska7xw = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "0zxmoslxata5k = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "0s7l95ovsd46m = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "1ca6vmyuf2af1 = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "009tk67fs3qjj = OK<br>", origin: "http://localhost", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
```

Comment: you use both `ob_start` and `ob_flush` on every record, you do not need `ob_start` at all, simply output per record it is same.

Comment: also you miss the double newlines after each echo. You have new lines on first echo but no newlines on catch block. Try to sleep(1) between each loop execution

Comment: I've tried to `sleep` but to no avail.

Comment: there mighty be a problem with the php framework you are using. The code suggets that this is a controller method. Can you add more details of the whole request. maybe the problem is there

Comment: What sort of details, sorry?